# Unable To set EnforceUniqueValue property to a column

Tags: custom-list

I have created a custom list using Visual Studio. Now I have a requirement to set unique value to a column. I tried to set `EnforceUniqueValue` Property to `true` in `Schema.xml`, but it is throwing an error while deploying:

> ExceptionMessage: This field must be indexed to enforce unique values. Source: AppWeb SourceName: App Web Deployment

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: ExceptionMessage: This field must be indexed to enforce unique values. Source: AppWeb SourceName: App Web Deployment

Comment: You must also set the Indexed property equal to true

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things you need to override the **GetValidatedString** method to be able to enforce unique values for a field other than the title field [method described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getvalidatedstring.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your schema.xml, you must include the `Indexed` property and set it to `true`. The same is required if you do it in event receiver code or through the user interface. Setting this will resolve your deployment error.